# Cisco switch command help - unused port finding

Tags: command, switch-statement, cisco, ports

I'm not a Cisco switch guru, so I will see who out there has a good idea for my problem.
Our switch closet is "full" meaning all the ports have something plugged in. I know many of these ports aren't connected to anything on the other end; meaning they are empty, but have a patch cable plugged in. I was hoping to look at the interface command somehow to find which ports haven't been used in, let's say 6 months.
I can do the basic switch commands, which haven't given me much hope for finding the unused ports quickly or efficiently. Maybe someone here can help with a command that would have an effective use for finding these "unused" empty ports.

Comment: Router configuration is not programming. This is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
clear counters

sh int | i input,|output,|^FastEth|GigabitEth|TenGiga|Vlan
```

The first command will clear interface counters. The second command will give you a summary of your interfaces and how many packets have been input/output. So if you clear the counters and you don't have any input/output packets after x-months, there is a good chance that the port isn't used. Further more, the last command will also tell you if the port is notconnected presently.

Example of output:

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/10 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
```

Answer (score -1):

***sh ver*** gives you the uptime of the switch : important for baseline of switch uptime / timer / packet flow / packet count

***sh int status*** gives you the port number and connection status : important for finding "not connected" switch ports

***sh int counters*** gives you the traffic flow on each port : this is where you look for "zero"

**BAM!!**
You've got your empty / non- used switch ports !! Use a vlookup function in excel and you quickly know what you can disconnect, according to your findings and determinations.